Keycloak returning 405 but no error message
Me and my colleagues have imported the same keycloak config. We have this code:
TokenRequest request = new TokenRequest(
    URI.create(String.format(TOKEN_PATH, url, realm)),
    new ClientID(clientId),
    new AuthorizationCodeGrant(
        new AuthorizationCode(authorizationCode),
        URI.create(redirectURI)),
    new Scope("openid", "profile"));

HTTPRequest httpRequest = request.toHTTPRequest();
HTTPResponse response = httpRequest.send();

There's nothing in the keycloak logs. Response is...

When I run this I get a response with status 405. When my colleagues try it, they get a 200. What settings could possibly be causing this?
